# How to set Text property of Combobox with DataTemplate when SelectedItem is null?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

The following code works until I try to visualize "-- Please Select Insurance--" when the SelectedInsurance is null:

```
 <Style x:Key="PrimaryInsuranceStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PrimaryInsurance.SelectedInsurance}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="-- Please Select Insurance --" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="InsuranceTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <!--Company Name-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
                    <!--Effective Date From-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="56" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
                    <!--Effective Date To-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="56" />
                    <!--Empty space-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
                    <!--Insurance Type-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XNotInEffect}"      Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}"       Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EffectiveDateFrom}" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="--" Grid.Column="3" TextAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EffectiveDateTo}"   Grid.Column="4" TextAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PolicyType}"        Grid.Column="6" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>



<ComboBox 
            Style="{StaticResource PrimaryInsuranceStyle}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="590,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="510" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.CanPickInsurance}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.AllPatientInsurance}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource InsuranceTemplate}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding PrimaryInsurance.SelectedInsurance}"
            />
```

How can Text property of the Combobox be set when the selectedItem has a DataTemplate and the selecteditem is null?

Note: The visualized Text is empty.

TIA

Comment: you cannot do this easily. Setting `Text` won't show anything on the ComboBox ***unless*** the `IsEditable` set to `true`. I guess in your case the `IsEditable` should be false (as by default). Usually almost what you see in the ComboBox when nothing dropped-down is the  `SelectionBoxItem`. However when `SelectedItem` is null, we cannot access to `SelectionBoxItem` to change its template via a hacky way (using `ItemTemplate` with some trigger). You should re-template your combobox by copying some sample template, modify it instead.

Comment: @Hopeless Sorry to hear that....Thanks :(